# intent not working in my app

Tags: java, android

i have created a messenger app and i dont find any error in my code but when i press my button it asks me to close the app..please do help me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendmessage(View view)
    {
        EditText textView=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String messageText=textView.getText().toString();
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,RecieveMessage.class);
        intent.putExtra("messages",messageText);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and this is my intented activity

```
public class RecieveMessage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieve_message);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message=intent.getStringExtra("messages");
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Please post the full logcat output with the exception and what line of code the error is on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    String data = extras.getString("messages");
```

Comment: Replace.. Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message=intent.getStringExtra("messages");

Comment: IT SAYS DECLARATION HERE IS NOT ALLOWED HERE

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieve_message);
        Bundle extras = Intent.getExtras();
        if(extras != null)
            String data = extras.getString("messages");
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("messages");

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your manifest.XML if the activity is registered.
2. The context try to use mainactivity.this

Hope it helps

Comment: <activity android:name=".RecieveMessage"></activity>

Comment: i think it is registered